# WebView size in JavaFX Stage

Tags: java, javafx, webview, javafx-2

I want to change the size of the `Stage` and `WebView` of a JavaFx application.

I can change the windows size but the browser size does not increases from 800px so the display of the html page does not fit all the windows.

It looks like this (note the light grey zone on the right):

[image]

This is some code of the page:

```
public class EfadosApp extends Application {
    private Scene scene;

    @Override public void start(Stage stage) {
        scene = new Scene(new Browser(), 1000,500);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
}

class Browser extends Region {
    final WebView browser = new WebView();
    final WebEngine webEngine = browser.getEngine();

    public Browser() {
        webEngine.load("www.oracle.com");
        getChildren().add(browser);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply fix this with extending for example [StackPane](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/StackPane.html) rather than `Region`:

```
class Browser extends StackPane {
    ...
}
```

The difference is that `Region` resizes the children to their preferred size :

> By default a Region inherits the layout behavior of its superclass,
>   Parent, which means that it will resize any resizable child nodes to
>   their preferred size, but will not reposition them. If an application
>   needs more specific layout behavior, then it should use one of the
>   Region subclasses: StackPane, HBox, VBox, TilePane, FlowPane,
>   BorderPane, GridPane, or AnchorPane.

While `StackPane` tries to resize its children to fit the content area:

> The stackpane will attempt to resize each child to fill its content
>   area. If the child could not be sized to fill the stackpane (either
>   because it was not resizable or its max size prevented it) then it
>   will be aligned within the area using the alignment property, which
>   defaults to Pos.CENTER.

This of course also means, if you use `Region` but either you set the [preferred size](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/web/WebView.html#setPrefSize-double-double-) of the `WebView` to "something big" like

```
browser.setPrefSize(5000, 5000);
```

or you bind the `heightProperty` and `widthProperty` of the `WebView` to the corresponding properties of the `Stage`,

```
Browser browser = new Browser();
browser.browser.prefHeightProperty().bind(stage.heightProperty());
browser.browser.prefWidthProperty().bind(stage.widthProperty());
scene = new Scene(browser, 1000, 500);
```

it will also work as you expect.